# How to generate a reference number by using customer name and year?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, int

I want to generate a unique number based on customer name and the date of birth.

If my customer name is  Chandra shekar and his date of birth is `28/12/1990`.

I want something like  `xxxx-1990`

`xxxx` should be a number which should be generate based on customer name.

How can I generate a number from string value?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did those value came from? are you referring with your database?

Comment: Assume `birth` is DateTime:  `string yr = birth.Year.ToString()`;

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Show your effort first..

Comment: Do you need to be able to get this number back from the year + name and know that it's *exactly* the number originally generated? That would be difficult without the number being large... any scheme which generates "small" numbers (like GetHashCode) will suffer from possible collisions.

Comment: are you using mysql for retreving name and DOB?

Comment: customer name and date of birth would not guarantee a unique identifier, instead you should look into AutoIcrement field in database or some otherway of generating unique identifier

Comment: No database reference. Just from front end Textbox and datetimepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky if you need to be able to guarantee uniqueness *immediately*. Any scheme which tries to convert a string to a "small" number (one which will always be smaller in terms of information than the original string) will always suffer from possible collisions.

So it really depends on your requirements. If you need to be able to reliably generate this ID later on give the name and number *purely* algorithmically, you've got a problem.

On the other hand, if you can store "name, date of birth, generated ID" in a table somewhere, then you could start by using a hash of some form (I wouldn't suggest using `GetHashCode` as there's no guarantee that it will stay stable over time, but some common cryptographic hash should be fine) and then look up the results in the table. You could use another part for uniqueness, too. For example, if the hash for "Fred Blogs" gave 1234, and so did the hash for "Jim Smith", you might end up with:

```
Fred Blogs => 1234-0-1990
Jim Smith =>  1234-1-1990
```

But then again, if you're in that situation you could consider just generating a globally unique ID to start with. It's all about working out the *exact* requirements before you try to solve them. As I say, you should abandon the idea of just "a number which is unique" - that's doomed due to the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

As Habib mentions, you also need to consider the possibility of multiple customers with the same name and birth date.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to generate a number from a string, you can use [GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx):

```
var customerName = "John Smith";
var yourReferenceNumber = customerName.GetHashCode();
```

Please note that this does not guarantee the uniqueness of your number, however.

Comment: Absolutely not. Hash codes make *no* guarantee of uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry, I was answering "How can I generate a number from string value?"

Comment: Well then let's make it even simpler and use `customerName.Length` - that's generating *a number* from a string, isn't it? The question starts with: "I want to generate a unique number..."

Comment: Well, hash codes are generally great for storing something into dictionaries, aren't them? String lenghts are not. I thought my answer could be helpful, in that case.

Comment: Hash codes only work for dictionaries because you can *also* use Equals in the fact of collisions. If you're trying to generate an ID which is meant to be unique, they *don't* work.

Comment: I agree with you, Jon, but the question was not specific about the "level" of uniqueness the OP would like to achieve nor he stated his intentions (db? dictionary?). :)

Comment: The question was pretty clear in stating that it needed to be unique, IMO. Also note that GetHashCode isn't suitable for *stored* generated numbers if you need to be able to generate the same number again - it would be entirely valid for the algorithm in GetHashCode to change over time, and IIRC it's already different between 32-bit and 64-bit CLRs.

Comment: I wonder what the difference would be between uniqueness and "full level of uniqueness". Show me that, and my wife will be "a little bit pregnant" tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

try to use code like this

```
var yr = DateTime.Parse("28/12/1990" , new CultureInfo("en-US")).Year;
var custName = "Chandra shekar";
var result = custName + yr ;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: That doesn't generate a *number* as the first part.

Comment: Nope, that's still going to be "Chandra shekar-1990" which isn't what the OP wanted...